# Executing php files in terminal vs in browser

Tags: php

I want to exec php file `test1.php` in file `test.php`. My problem is when I manualy run script `test.php` in terminal on the server(`php /home/users/xh/*****/WWW/BP/test.php`) it will do the job and exec the `test1.php`. But when I open `test.php` in the browser, it will not exec the `test1.php`. I added the +x permissions to the folder and to the .php files but it do not work anyway- `ls -ld : drwxr-xr-x`,`ls -l: -rwxr-xr-x` (on both test1 and test)

Here is `test.php`:

```
<?php
echo "including test1\n";
exec('php -f /home/users/xh/*****/WWW/BP/test1.php');
echo "end";
```

`test1.php`:

```
<?php

$db = mysql_connect('localhost:/var/run/mysql/mysql.sock', '*******', '*******');
if (!$db) die('cannot connect'.mysql_error());
if (!mysql_select_db('******', $db)) die('db not available '.mysql_error());

$var=mysql_set_charset("UTF8", $db);

if (!($result =   mysql_query("INSERT INTO table VALUES ('abcdefg','100','20','3','3')", $db))) {
    echo "insert not successful";
}
else
    echo "insert successful";
```

EDIT: when in run script `test1.php` by `shell_exec()` it whill show this warning:

```
Warning: shell_exec() [function.shell-exec]: Cannot execute using backquotes in Safe Mode
```

Comment: Apache may not have the correct permissions to execute the file. Try outputting the result of exec into a log file

Comment: output:array(0) { } 
return code:127

Comment: I added +x permissions, but it not helped,on the directory and on the .php files

Comment: Eddited the post, seems like Safe mode preventing from exec. I have read that safe mode has been removed from php 5.6, but this is exactly version I am using. Is it possible that when I run script by `php test1.php` it will run another version of php?